# Proof that the tangent map (differential) is linear

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

I am following these notes [https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/lecnotes/lie2002prereq.pdf](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Eban00101/lecnotes/lie2002prereq.pdf) (Tangent vectors are defined using equivalent clases of curves) and on page 4 it says that the map $T_xf $ is linear which should follow from lemma 1.1 and corollary 1.2
which are:

[image]

[image]

I am having trouble to see why it is so. According to the diagram:

[image]

$T_xf = T_{f(x)}\circ D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})(\chi(x))\circ T_x\chi$

From Corollary 1.2 , $T_x \chi$ and $T_{f(x)} \psi$ are linear. They act on tangent vectors like this:

if $\gamma'(0) \in T_x X$, then  $T_x \chi (\gamma'(0) ) = \frac{d}{dt}(\chi \circ \gamma)(0)$

I don't think we need lemma 1.1. (do we?) Moreover it looks to me that $D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})(\chi(x))$ is a constant function because it is a function (the derivative of the transition map) between euclidean spaces evaluated at a fixed point , $(\chi(x))$ and therefore it is not linear. What am I doing wrong? Maybe this is not a constant function, but then how does it acts on its arguments?

It looks to me that the statement in yellow is wrong too, shouldn't that be a multiplication rather that a composition? (maybe this is part of the problem? But that seems to be only part of the proof of corollary 1.2, I interpreted it as multiplication so that for any two charts  $\chi$ and $\psi$ differ by a multiplicative constant factor)

Can someone shed some light?

**Edit:**

[image]
**Edit 2**

In page 3 of the notes it is defined the following notation : $T_x\chi c'(0) = \frac{d}{dt}[\chi\circ c](0)$. Using this equation $(2)$ can be rewritten as:

$T_x\psi c'(0)=D(\tau)(\chi(x))T_x\chi c'(0)$.

And just as for instance when I have function $f$ and $g$, $f(x)=g(x) \forall x$ in their domains I can write $f=g$, In the above example I can leave out the argument  $c'(0)$ and write:

$T_x\psi =D(\tau)(\chi(x))T_x\chi $

which should be the expression in yellow were it not by that $\circ$ that is mysteriously popping out of nowhere, which I think I am proving it should be a multiplication

Furthermore the equation in (2) must be a multiplication between  $D(\tau)(\chi(x))$ and $\frac{d}{dt}\chi \circ c(t)|_{t=0}$ because a multiplication is what I get from applying the chain rule and equation (1) in the notes.
Meaning that my proof of this...

[image]

is as follows:

$\frac{d}{dt}\psi \circ c(t)|_0=\frac{d}{dt}\psi\circ\chi^{-1}\circ \chi \circ c(t)|_0 =\frac{d}{dt}\tau \circ \chi \circ c(t)|_0 = D(\tau)(\chi(c(0)))\frac{d}{dt}\chi \circ c (t)|_{t=0} = D(\tau)(\chi(x))\frac{d}{dt}\chi \circ c (t)|_{t=0}$

Comment: The derivative evaluated at a point is a linear map between their tangent spaces. For example, if f:R^2 -> R^2 is the identity function, then the derivative at any point is the identity function on tangent spaces, and if you choose bases in a natural way, this linear transformation can be represented by the 2x2 identity matrix, not a number. In single variable calculus, the derivative (at a point) is still a linear map, but a 1x1 matrix, i.e. a number or constant c, but as a map on tangent spaces R ->R is multiplcation by c, not the constant function c. TLDR: the notes are correct

Comment: @usr0192 So if $c'(0)$ is a tangent vector, $D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})(\chi(x))(c'(0))=Ic'(0)=c'(0)?$ or should it be some other matrix? Any link where i can see this proof in a general setting?

Comment: well, if f:R^2->R^2 is the identity function, i.e. f(x,y)=(x,y), the Df=I  is 2x2 identity matrix. But for a general map f, no it usually wont be I. For example if f(x,y)=(x^2, xy+y^2) then what is Df at the point (1,1)? It will be a 2x2 matrix. Any multivariable calc text will do, I learned it in Munkres or spivaks Analysis on manifolds

Comment: @usr0192  So should I see the composition highlighted in yellow  as a multiplication by a matrix as well? why is so? It seems strange to me, Would it be ok to write it as multiplication, if you saw the notes that equation is just equation (2) of the previous page which I pasted as a picture just now (take a look at the end of the post) written in terms of $T_x\chi$ and $T_x\psi$ instead of $d/dt...$ and in (2) a multiplication was used instead of composition! Therefore I think that yellow equation is wrong unless this is common notation that I am not aware of

Comment: well, the yellow you highlighted is composition of functions, so is ocrrect as written, but when the functions are expressed as matrices, then the composition turns into matrix multiplication (this is a of not the reason why matrix multiplication is defined the way it is in linear algebra- e.g. not the Hadamard prod.

Comment: An unhelpful comment: The fact that the author chose to use $\chi$ (out of all possible Greek letters) when he's working with $X$ and $x$ shows a sincere lack of judgment and I would question whether the text is a good choice to try to read.

Comment: I looked at the notes to see the author’s notation in (2). There D( )() is a linear transformation taking as input something in R^n, namely  d/dt(stuff)…. and giving as output something in R^n. So as written it is not multiplication, but AFTER choosing coordinates/bases, then D()() can be represented as a matrix, d/dt() part as a vector and then you get matrix multiplication. What the author has written is correct, but I recommend either working out a concrete simple example and/or using a supplemental text to see the same from a different perspectiv

Comment: I suggest that it's not always productive to try to understand every detail of what's written in a book or paper. Study it as carefully as you can, but, once you have a good sense of what the author is trying to do, try to work out the details yourself. You don't have to do things exactly as the author does it.

Comment: Your confusion is based in notational conventions. Quite often one identifies a linear map with its matrix in given bases and one also writes $Ax$ instead of $A(x)$. 
So if you have an identity for linear maps like $Ax=BCx$ for all $x$, then what really is meant is $A(x)=(B\circ C)(x)$ and this implies $A=B\circ C$. The multiplication that turns into composition is not mysterious, it’s just notation.

Comment: @SvenPistre So if I write the expression in yellow using multiplication it is still correct? Or must I write it using the composition sign?

Comment: Well, it’s an expression involving linear maps (not matrices per se), so I’d argue that writing this as composition is the way to go. If you apply these to vectors, you might omit the $\circ$-symbol. 
But I think the gist of it for you should be „Be aware of different notation and conventions.“ Usually you’ll see something like that written at the beginning of a book or so. But maybe, as @TedShifrin already commented, this might be a text which leaves some things up to the reader which could have been easily cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

The author considers charts $\chi : U \to U'$ with $x \in U$ and $\psi : V \to V'$ with $f(x) \in V$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. This yields a differentiable map $\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1} : U' \to V'$ between open subsets of Eucidean spaces. At each point $q \in U'$ it has a derivative denoted by $D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1} ) \mid_q$ or $D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})(q)$. This is a linear map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. It is in general not constant.

If you accept that diagram $(3)$ commutes, then you  get
$$T_xf = (T_{f(x)}\psi)^{-1} \circ D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})(\chi(x))\circ T_x\chi .$$
Here it is essential that $T_{f(x)}\psi$ is a linear isomorphism as proved in Lemmas 1.1 (bijectivity) and 1.2 (linearity).

Let us now recall some fact from multivariable calculus.

Given a map $F : U' \to V'$ between open subsets $U' \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $V' \subset \mathbb R^m$, the derivative of $F$ at a point $p \in U'$ (if it exists) is linear map $DF(p) : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. One also writes $DF \mid_p$ for this map. We can represent the linear map $DF(p)$ by the Jacobian matrix $JF(p) = JF \mid_p = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}(p) \end{pmatrix}$ of $F$ at $p$. If we understand elements of Euclidean spaces as *column vectors*, we get $DF \mid_p(v) = JF \mid_p \cdot v$, where  $\cdot$ denotes matrix multiplication.

If $n =1$, then $DF \mid_p$ is a linear map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$. It is uniquely determined by the value $DF \mid_p(1) \in \mathbb R^m$ which is nothing else than the "ordinary derivative" $F'(p) = \dfrac{dF}{dt}(p)$ with components $F'_i(p) = \dfrac{dF_i}{dt}(p)$.

Given another map $G : V' \to W'$, the chain rule says that $D(G \circ F)(p) = DG(F(p)) \circ DF(p)$ or $D(G \circ F) \mid_p = DG \mid_{F(p)} \circ DF \mid_p$. The symbol $\circ$ denotes composition of functions. In terms of Jacobians this says $J(G \circ F) \mid_p = JG \mid_{F(p)} \cdot JF \mid_p$. Moreover, if $n =1$, the chain rule is equivalent to
$$\dfrac{d(G \circ F)}{dt}(p) = D(G \circ F) \mid_p(1)  = (DG \mid_{F(p)} \circ DF \mid_p)(1) = DG \mid_{F(p)}(DF \mid_p(1)) \\=  DG \mid_{F(p)}(\dfrac{dF}{dt}(p)) .$$

Let us come to the yellow statement.

For each chart $\chi : U \to U'$ with $x \in U$ the author defines
$$T_x\chi :T_xM \to \mathbb R^n, T_x\chi(c'(0)) = \frac{d (\chi \circ c)}{dt}(0) = \frac{d (\chi \circ c)}{dt} \mid_{t=0}.$$
Here $c'(0)$ denotes the equivalence class $[c] \in T_x M  = \mathcal C_x/\sim$ of the curve $c$, it is not a derivative in the usual sense. Such only exist for curves with range $\mathbb R^n$. For example, $\chi \circ c$ is such a curve and we could write $(\chi \circ c)'(0)$ instead of $\frac{d (\chi \circ c)}{dt}(0)$. I guess the autors wants to avoid this because of his convention that such expressions denote equivalence classes of curves.

If $\psi : V \to V'$ is another chart with $x \in V$, then we have the transition function $\tau = \psi \circ \chi^{-1}$ which is differentiable. Then $\tau \circ (\chi \circ c) = \psi \circ c$ and the chain rule gives
$$D(\psi \circ c) \mid_{t=0} = D\tau \mid_{\chi(c(0))} \circ D(\chi \circ c)\mid _{t=0} = D\tau \mid_{\chi(x)} \circ D(\chi \circ c)\mid _{t=0}$$
or
$$\frac{d(\psi \circ c)}{dt}\mid_{t=0} = D\tau \mid_{\chi(x)}\left(\frac{d(\chi \circ c)}{dt}\mid _{t=0}\right) .$$
This is the formally correct version of $(2)$. The author writes it  a bit sloppy as $\frac{d(\psi \circ c)}{dt}\mid_{t=0} = D\tau \mid_{\chi(x)}\frac{d(\chi \circ c)}{dt}\mid _{t=0}$. Anyway, inserting the definitions of $T_x\chi, T_x\psi$ we get
$$T_x\psi(c'(0))  =  D\tau \mid_{\chi(x)}(T_x\chi(c'(0))) =  (D\tau \mid_{\chi(x)} \circ T_x\chi)(c'(0)) .$$
Without the argument $c'(0)$ this reads as
$$T_x\psi = D\tau \mid_{\chi(x)} \circ T_x\chi = D\tau(\chi(x)) \circ T_x\chi .$$

Comment: Aren't you missing the "D"s in the third sentence?

Comment: Why is it  essential that $T_{f(x)}\psi$ is an isomorphism to state that T_xf is linear? Isn't Corollary 1.2 enough? My reasoning was that $T_x\chi$ and $(T_{f(x)}\psi)^{-1}$ are linear and I accept that the central term is linear, then the composition of three linear maps are linear. Maybe I need it to state that the central term is linear?

Comment: As an example of why I think $D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1} ) \mid_q$ is constant consider $F:=\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1}$is a map $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2 $. Let's say $F([x,y]^T)=(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})([x,y]^T)=[x^2+y,x−y^2]^T$ and $q=[1,2]^T$. Then $DF$ is just the Jacobian: $DF([x,y]^T)=D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})([x,y]^T)=[2x,1 ; 1 ,-2y]$ writting "$|_q$" means to me x=1, y=2, so just another way of writing DF(q) : $D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})|_q=DF|_q=DF(q)=[2(1), 1 ; 1 , -2(2)]= [2, 1 ; 1 , -4]$ Isn't this a constant(matrix)?that is an ...

Comment: ....$\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2 $  const funct? There are no x or y left and $q$ is supposed to be fixed. I suspect you want me to  look at it as the matrix of a linear transformation?  but in that case the function would be  $DF|_q([x,y]^T)= [2, 1 ; 1 , -4][x,y]^T $ but how could that be if $x$ and $y$ were already evaluated at $q$. And then just as an $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ function composed with anything will give a constant, I think the former constant matrix makes the expresion $T_xf$ a constant. What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: @mathlover $D$ added. That $T_{f(x)}$ is an isomorphism is needed because its **inverse** occurs in $T_xf = (T_{f(x)}\psi)^{-1} \circ D(\psi \circ f \circ \chi^{-1})(\chi(x))\circ T_x\chi$. Corollary 1.2 only says that it is linear and then theoretically it could be the zero map. This would not allow to say anything about $T_xf$. I would reformulate Lemma 1.2 by saying that $T_x\chi$ is a linear isomorphism.

Comment: If you have a differentiable map $F: U' \to V'$ between open subset of Euclidean spaces, then for each $p \in U'$ the derivative of $F$ at $p$ is a linear map $DF \mid_p : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. A linear map being constant means that it is the zero map. But there is no reason why we should have $DF \mid_p = 0$ in general. You may think of $DF \mid_p$ as the Jacobian matrix of $F$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that the function $DF : U' \to Hom(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ associating to each $p \in U'$ its derivative is constant. This may the case in special cases, but not in general. But whether or not $DF$ is constant, in the yellow part you compose two linear maps.

Comment: Could you please take a look at edit 2 in my post, there I am explaing why that composition sign in yellow seems to me to have popped out of nowhere